# avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

Tags: arduino

I am making a project that takes temperature from temperature sensor and then pass it to arduino Uno and send to pc through Bluetooth.

When I used arduino sample program (blink) it worked fine and loaded the program but when I used Linux terminal to load my code,it gave me this error:

> avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide some more information. i.e.: Linux version, what linux device is the programmer (usb serial) /dev/???, do you have permissions as your current user to read/write from the device? The more information you can provide the more likely SO can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in linux maybe you have to run the program as sudo
it may have something to do with your privileges over the port also.
im not on linux anymore but it should point you on the right direction.